# How to parse JSON object at jsp

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I wauld parse JSON object(List) which the i pass from controller. I want to convert my JSON object in html, but I want to extract each parameter separately.

```
@JsonView(View.Public.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/updatecomments", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Commentary> updateCommentary(@RequestParam int idEvent) {
    System.out.println("updatecomm: " + idEvent);
    Event event = eventService.findById(idEvent);
    List<Commentary> comments = event.getComments();
    return comments;
}
```

when i parse with this function it's work:

```
<script>
    function updateComments() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "/updatecomments",
            method : 'GET',
            data : {
                idEvent: ${event.getId()},
            },
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(results){
                alert("succes");
                var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"
                    + JSON.stringify(results, null, 4) + "</pre>";
                $('#feedback').html(json);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

but when i would parse with this code, it isn't work:

```
<script>
    function updateComments() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "/updatecomments",
            method : 'GET',
            data : {
                idEvent: ${event.getId()},
            },
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(results){
                alert("succes");

                <c:forEach var = "comment" items="${results}">
                    alert(${comment.description});
                    alert(1);
                </c:forEach>
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

This function also does not work

```
var comments = $.parseJSON(results);
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: In your ajax request (for 2nd type) the page wasn't load. so the value doesn't render in the jsp page. jstl updates value in jsp page on page load.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know it.